2-DVRP using optaplanner: problem of efficiently routing two different vehicle entities, one is dependent on the other
I have a problem statement, where we need to optimize the two agents of vehicles. One is a service vehicle and the others are service engineers. The service vehicles are supposed to reach multiple sites and so does the service engineers. the following are the constraints:

Service can only happen when both the service engineer and service vehicle has reached
Service vehicle can visit the sites in any order
Service engineers are more expensive and hence we have more service engineers than service trucks
One service engineer can only work at one site at a time, and then only after finishing move to the next location
Service vehicle will finish going to go to all the locations and then come to a depot and then go out for servicing once again

Here the route of the vehicle as well as the engineer seems dependent and I am thinking of using 2 dynamic vehicle routing problem to solve, it. Need help to understand if this is the right approach and has anyone solved anything similar using optaplanner?
We had tried a lot of heursitics and optimising each of the activities in isolation, but none of them were optimal, hence looking to have a synchronized solution

This is multi-vehicle visits. The requirement that 2 vehicles can drive independently, but meet up at a customer together at 15:00.
It's a very difficult constraint to implement, but it is possible in OptaPlanner/Timefold.
For our Field Service Routing implementation on app.timefold.ai, it took us 3 months. The complexity lies in implementing the loop detection (especially incrementally so it scales too). The Timefold Solver team is working on supporting such constructs out-of-the-box, but that will take a while.

@GeoffreyDeSmet is it possible to get any professional help from Timefold team if we want to implement this?

Try our Field Service Routing model on app.timefold.ai. It has a free trial. I'd love to try to explain how to implement multi-vehicle visits incrementally, but it's pure rocket science. Our solver team is working on building constructs to use it easily in any model.
